# Is it possible to remove the the lined filter selection box in AG-Grid headers?

Tags: html, ag-grid

I'd like to remove the selection options along with the padding-right from this column if that is possible. The selection options can be found to the right of every column header when you hover over it.

The purpose of this is to ensure that the column can be made to be as narrow as possible while still showing a 3 letter long header.

[Picture of the button I'd like to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc1wQ.png)

[What the "more options" button displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Bv7e.png)

Is this something I can add to these colDefs to make it so that the selectionoptions = False?

```
defaultColDef: {
flex: 1,
minWidth: 50,
sortable: true,
resizable: true
```

},

Thanks!

Comment: It's on the grid options : `suppressCellSelection: true`, you have also the `isRowSelectable` callback if you want to disable/enable the selection of the whole row depending on a condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two settings you are looking for.

The first you will add to columnDefs: [`suppressMenu: true`](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-menu/#showing-the-column-menu)
This will hide the menu on the column headers.

The second will be added to the gridOptions: [`suppressContextMenu: true`](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-menu/#showing-the-column-menu) This one will suppress the AG Grid context menu when you right click on the grid.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think the padding can be removed so it doesn't block off more letters like how it does in the first picture?